# Why AJAX call to Controller Action sending only single value?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send two parameters to my controller action using jQuery's AJAX method. But Controller is showing value for the first parameter duplicated to second parameter. Why is this happening?

AJAX Call:

```
$('#btnSendTestEmail').click(function () {
            var dataObject = JSON.stringify({
                TestEmail: 'TestEmailAddress',
                NotificationEmail: 'NotificationAddresss'
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: '/SystemVariables/SendTestEmail',
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                processData: false,
                data: dataObject,
                success: function (response) { },
                error: function (response) { }
            }); 
        });
```

Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendTestEmail(string TestEmail, string NotificationEmail)
{
    string emailAddress = String.IsNullOrEmpty(TestEmail) ? SysNotificationEmail : TestEmail;
      ...
     return View();
}
```

The above code is showing values as 'TestEmailAddress' for both of the parameters of controller i.e. TestEmail & NotificationEmail

Comment: Can you call the endpoint with successful serialization without using JSON.stringify?

Comment: Try removing the contentType: 'application/json', i've had issues with that before

Comment: Yeah, what Rav said, but try removing ALL non essential AJAX attributes one at a time. Only "url", "type", "data", and "dataType" should be needed. Data type might even be inferred, if I recall. But remove each one by one.

Comment: Remove processData. If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, then only set this option to false.

Comment: @RossBush No, it sends me null values if I dont use it,

Comment: @Rav, tried it already, got same problem after that,

Comment: @HastaTamang, Tried it did not work out.

Comment: @Sourabh it's working for me correctly, i've posted your code and it works fine. Is there any kind of model binding or special routeconfig? Try creating a new MVC application and a vanilla controller with the exact javascript you've got in your example.

Comment: @Sourabh one thing i've noticed is that your sending back a view? should you be returning some JSON? is this a copy of your code?

Comment: @Rav Yes, its inside a Razor Form block. But I dont see that should be issue.. I might be wrong. it does not change it's behaviour no matter what return type i use. I tried with JSON too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model so there is something to bind to:

```
public class EmailModel
{
    public string TestEmail { get; set; }
    public string NotificationEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Then accept the model in the controller, it will then know the structure to bind to:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendTestEmail(EmailModel model)
    {
        string emailAddress = model.TestEmail;
        string test = model.NotificationEmail;
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you post data to an action in ASP.NET MVC you need to have only one model to `bind` in the action.

This is the default behaviour of the [DefaultModelBinder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

You need to create a class with these properties and keep only one parameter in the action.

```
public ActionResult SendTestEmail(YourModel model)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSendTestEmail', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post('/SystemVariables/SendTestEmail', 
      {
        TestEmail: 'TestEmailAddress',
        NotificationEmail: 'NotificationAddresss'
      })
   .done(function(response){
      console.log(response);

    })
   .fail(function(xhr, exception){
      console.log(response);

    })

})
```

Comment: Nope both parameters still show 'TestEmailAddress' as value. TBH i'm completely confused why is it showing both values as same.

Comment: It's ASP MVC Code, you can see method where I'm catching call is above named   SendTestEmail(string TestEmail, string NotificationEmail)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not using a json object to send the data? would be something like this:

```
 $('#btnSendTestEmail').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/SystemVariables/SendTestEmail',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: {'TestEmail': "TestEmailAddres", 'NotificationEmail': "NotificationAdress"},
            success: function (response) { },
            error: function (response) { }
        }); 
    });
```